# how to use NextJS redirect in config file

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to use nextjs redirect function to redirect old paths to a new paths and the server should return status code 301 once users reach the old paths. I have a config file like this:

```
module.exports = (phase, { defaultConfig }) => {
  const config = withFonts(
    withImages(
      withSass({
        publicRuntimeConfig: {
          CMS_HOST: process.env.CMS_HOST,
        },
        trailingSlash: true,
        exportPathMap: function() {
          return {
            "/": { page: "/" }
          };
        },
        cssModules: false,
        env: {
          CMS_HOST: process.env.CMS_HOST,
          CMS_HOST_DEV: process.env.CMS_HOST_DEV
        }
      })
    )
  )

  return config;
};
```

I tried to add a function like below but it does not work:

```
  module.exports = (phase, { defaultConfig }) => {
  const config = withFonts(
    withImages(
      withSass({
        publicRuntimeConfig: {
          CMS_HOST: process.env.CMS_HOST,
        },
        trailingSlash: true,
        exportPathMap: function() {
          return {
            "/": { page: "/" }
          };
        },
        redirects() {
          return [{
            source: '/team/:slug*',
            destination: '/about-us/:slug*',
            permanent: true,
          }]
        },
        cssModules: false,
        env: {
          CMS_HOST: process.env.CMS_HOST,
          CMS_HOST_DEV: process.env.CMS_HOST_DEV
        }
      })
    )
  )

  return config;
};
```

Thanks,

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: it always return 404 status code instead of 301 for redirecting. But I think I figured it out by updating NextJS version to 9.5.5 from 9.2.1 and remove the trailingSlash property. I have no idea what happened but it works now. Thanks anyway.

Comment: That's because redirects have only been introduced in Next.js 9.5.

Comment: true, I didn't read docs carefully, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `async` for the `redirect`

> `redirects` is an async function that expects an array to be returned
> holding objects with `source`, `destination`, and `permanent` properties

**Reference**

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects

Answer (score 0):

I updated NextJS to 9.5.5 from 9.2.1 and it works now. Thank you.